# Did you twist my words?

Tags: beginner, c, strings, programming-challenge

#### Challenge

Given two strings, determine if the second string is a rotation of the first.

#### Specifications

1. The first argument is a path to a file.
2. The file contains multiple lines.
3. Each line is a test case represented by two comma separated strings.
4. For each test case print out True/False if the second string is a rotation of the first.

**Sample Input**

> Code,deCo
> Review,wRevie
> testcase,casetoast

**Sample Output**

> True
> True
> False

[Source](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/76/)

**My solution**

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_LENGTH 64

char* str_mul(char* str, int times) {
    char *string_multiplied = malloc(sizeof(str) * times + 1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= times; i++) {
        strcat(string_multiplied, str);
    }
    return string_multiplied;    
}

bool is_rotated(char *original, char *test_case) {
    int original_length = strlen(original);
    char *rotation_superset = str_mul(original, 2);
    bool is_substring = strstr(rotation_superset, test_case) != NULL;
    return original_length == strlen(test_case) && is_substring;
}

char* parse_and_evaluate(char *line) {
    const char tokens[] = ",\n\r";
    char *original = strtok(line, tokens);
    char *test_case = strtok(NULL, tokens);
    return is_rotated(original, test_case) ? "True" : "False";
}

int main(int argc, char *args[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File path not provided. Exiting...\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (argc > 2) {
        puts("Excessive arguments, only the first will be considered.");
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(args[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error");
        return 1;
    }

    char line[LINE_LENGTH];
    while (fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, file)) {
        printf("%s\n", parse_and_evaluate(line));
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: I was going to write an answer, but I ended up [completely rewriting your code](http://pastebin.com/GVZV3CU3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're bleeding memory for every line in the file.  This is probably ok for the challenge, however it's a good idea to get into the habit of cleaning up after yourself.

The call to `malloc` in `str_mul` needs to have a corresponding `free` call somewhere to release the memory.  Looking at your program in it's current state, the easiest way to do that is probably in the `is_rotated` method like so:

```
bool is_rotated(char *original, char *test_case) {
    int original_length = strlen(original);
    char *rotation_superset = str_mul(original, 2);
    bool is_substring = strstr(rotation_superset, test_case) != NULL;
    free(rotation_superset);
    return original_length == strlen(test_case) && is_substring;
}
```

I'd be tempted to actually move the `malloc` into the same method and pass the buffer into the `str_mul` method so that the allocation and release are at the same level.  This would also allow you to simply declare a local on the stack in `is_rotated`, rather than needing to use malloc:

```
void str_mul(char* str, char *string_multiplied, int times) {
    string_multiplied[0] = '\0';
    for (int i = 1; i <= times; i++) {
        strcat(string_multiplied, str);
    }
}

bool is_rotated(char *original, char *test_case) {
    int original_length = strlen(original);
    char rotation_superset[LINE_LENGTH*2];
    str_mul(original, rotation_superset, 2);
    bool is_substring = strstr(rotation_superset, test_case) != NULL;
    return original_length == strlen(test_case) && is_substring;
}
```

**malloc Vs calloc**

`malloc` isn't guaranteed to return zero initialized memory.  Since you're using strcat to append to the buffer, you should really ensure that the memory is a null terminated array.  You can either do that by initially null terminating it (as in my example above), or by using [calloc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm) instead.

Comment: `char rotation_superset[LINE_LENGTH*2];` --> `char rotation_superset[LINE_LENGTH*2 + 1];`

Comment: @chux the original contains a maximum string of `LINE_LENGTH - 1` (it already contains a null terminator from the `fgets` call).  `str_mul` copies the string into the buffer twice, so really we need `(LINE_LENGTH - 1)*2 + 1` or `(LINE_LENGTH * 2) - 1`, but `(LINE_LENGTH*2)` seemed close enough.  Am I missing something?

Comment: My error, thought code was `char rotation_superset[original_length*2];` (a VLA). but I see this answer well uses the macro `LINE_LENGTH`.  Part of the source of my error was OP using `...LENGTH` when `....SIZE` better matches.  `...LENGTH` with string code hints at the _length_ of a string, not its _size_.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [@forsvarir](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/142107/29485) good answer:

Code is broken

`str` is a pointer.  `malloc(sizeof(str) * times + 1);`  allocates memory for a bunch of *pointers*

```
char* str_mul(char* str, int times) {

    // bad
    // char *string_multiplied = malloc(sizeof(str) * times + 1);

    // Corrected
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char *string_multiplied = malloc(len * times + 1);
    string_multiplied[0] = '\0';  // also null character terminate

    for (int i = 1; i <= times; i++) {
        strcat(string_multiplied, str);
    }
...
```

Efficiency, do string length compare test `original_length == strlen(test_case)` first.  With mis-matched lengths, call to `str_mul()` not needed.